# log4j redirect few logs to separate file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, tomcat7

I have a tomcat java web application which uses log4j. Can I specify some property in log4j to redirect logs of particular package classes to separate file from rest of other files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For example, log files for your two packages are:

```
com.abhi.packageOne;  ->  packageOneFile.log
com.abhi.packageTwo;  ->  packageTwoFile.log
```

Add rootLogger as file or console. You can keep any log level i.e. trace, info, errror etc as per your requirements

```
log4j.rootLogger=Debug, file
```

You have to create two new appenders for your two packages

```
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.File=/path/main.log
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.PACKAGE_ONE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.PACKAGE_ONE.File=/path/packageOneFile.log
log4j.appender.PACKAGE_ONE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.PACKAGE_TWO=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.PACKAGE_TWO.File=/path/packageTwoFile.log
log4j.appender.PACKAGE_TWO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

You need to set additivity accordingly.

**What is addictivity ?**

In order to avoid redundancy in logs, we can use Log4j additivity. Just set the additivity property of an Log4j logger to false and then the log messages which are coming to that logger will not be propagated to it’s parent loggers. So, our new Log4j configuration file would be:

```
log4j.additivity.com.abhi.packageOne=false
log4j.additivity.com.abhi.packageTwo=false

log4j.logger.com.abhi.packageOne=DEBUG, PACKAGE_ONE
log4j.logger.com.abhi.packageTwo=DEBUG, PACKAGE_TWO

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, MAIN_LOG
```

Where MAIN_LOG is your regular log file. If you want to print logs from PACKAGE_ONE and PACKAGE_TWO in MAIN_LOG as well, then include below line.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, MAIN_LOG , PACKAGE_ONE , PACKAGE_TWO
```

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, MAIN_LOG , PACKAGE_ONE, PACKAGE_TWO  what does this statement do ?Can you explain in detail ?
and also log4j.additivity.com.abhi.packageOne=false as well as log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, MAIN_LOG , PACKAGE_ONE are required at same time ?

Comment: I defined the logger in same way.In my case logs are coming on console instead of file, I haven't defined console appender anywhere - what could be the reason?

Comment: You need to add ' log4j.rootLogger=debug, file ' above all these statements. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Let me know if you need any more help, else accept the answer. :P

Comment: Where have you specified rolling file name FileNamePattern ? which dependency need to be included for rolling file based on timebased rolling policy and whats the format for that?

Comment: By default file.log is rolled to file.log.yyyy-MM-dd or file.log.curSizeRollBackup. 

But if you want to specify fileNamePattern, you can set the PreserveLogFileNameExtension property on the RollingFileAppender.

Have a look at link : 
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.PreserveLogFileNameExtension.html

Comment: Also if you want timebased rolling policy, you should use DailyRollingRollingFileAppender.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this configuration for logging and you can also change the path of log file.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/test.log   // change your path
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.com.amstech=DEBUG
```

Comment: where is the package name whose logs will be redirected to log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/test.log  and where it is specified rest logs will go to default catalina.out ?